# In the second iteration in the FOR loop, onwards, object returns me null

Tags: java, android

I have a variable that gets the instance of a database (ROOM) and does a select, returning object, CidVo.

```
private AppDataBase appDataBase;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atendimento_tab);

appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(this);
}
```

In a return of an asynchronous task, I make this query. I need the CidVo corresponding to what was returned to me by the asynchronous task, the CidVo's are recorded in the database and yes, there are correspondences of them in that base.

The problem is in the second iteration onwards of the FOR loop.

Why does it happen?

For loop:

```
@Override
    public void retornoAsyncTaskResultPredict(AsyncTaskResult<Retorno> asyncTaskResult) {
        if (asyncTaskResult.getExceptionResult() == null) {

            RetornoPredicaoCid predicaoCidVo = (RetornoPredicaoCid) asyncTaskResult.getResult();

            if (predicaoCidVo.getRetorno() != null) {

                List<PredicaoCidVo> predCid = predicaoCidVo.getRetorno();
                List<CidVo> predictedText = new ArrayList<>();
                List<CidVo> predictedText1 = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0;i<predCid.size();i++) {
                    //appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(this);
                    CidVo cidVo = appDataBase.getCidDao().getCidVo(predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted());
                    CidVo cidVo1 = appDataBase.getCid(this, predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted());
                    predictedText1.add(cidVo1);
                    predictedText.add(cidVo);
                }


            }
    }
```

AppDataBase:

```
@Database(entities = {CidVo.class}, version = 8, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

 public abstract CidDao getCidDao();

    private static AppDataBase appDataBase;

    public static AppDataBase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (null == appDataBase) {
            appDataBase = buildDataBaseInstance(context);
        }
        return appDataBase;
    }

    private static AppDataBase buildDataBaseInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDataBase.class,
                "AutoCompleteVo")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }

    //CID predicted
    public CidVo getCid(Context context, String idCidVo) {
        if (appDataBase == null) {
            appDataBase = AppDataBase.getInstance(context);
        }
        return appDataBase.getCidDao().getCidVo("%" + idCidVo + "%");
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface CidDao {
    //CID
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAllCID(List<CidVo> cidVos);

    @Query("Select * from CidVo WHERE idCid = :idCid")
    CidVo getCidVo(String idCid);

}
```

The first iteration of the loop returns normally, but from the second on, returns null, the select.

Edit:

Edit:

If I select the variable (`appdatabase`) (ALT + F8) and place the code path manually, the query returns the data to me.

Comment: The application runs normally, and I get returned in the query, in the first iteration, the corresponding data, but from the second on, even if there are items, it returns me null.

Answer (score 0):

In the second iteration on, the items came to come with a space at the beginning or end, causing the problem. Solved with a simple `.trim();`

```
predCid.get(i).getTextPredicted ().trim()
```